# node js + jade printing passed variable in jade file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

Yes i feel guilty asking such a novice question.

```
app.get('/skumanagement/:id', function (req, res){      
var options = req.params.id;    // req.params.id = itemidx
database.skuGetDetail(options, function (error, data){
  winston.log('info', "SKU MANAGEMENT DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
  if (error) {
    winston.log('error', 'ERROR:: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    throw error;
  }
  else {
    res.render('sku_item_detail', data);
  }
});
});
```

SKU MANAGEMENT DATA produced from database.skuGetDetail: 
{"result":[{"merchantid":"00CA00000010","merchantname":"Mexon","itemidx":572,
"category":"Online Music","type":"1","title":"15Minutes","sku":"15Minutes","pricetype":"0","minprice":0.5,"maxprice":0.5,"imageurl":"http://","description":"15Minutes for Test","submitdate":"2011-03-23T06:40:00.000Z","lastupdated":"2011-06-03T18:51:00.000Z"}]

then I pass those data too render sku_item_detail which is jade template.

```
           p
               td
               th submit Date : #{data.sku}
               td
```

however adding those #{data.sku} will not work.

I want to print out those data I passed using jade.

I am open to other suggestion methods since I do not know if this method is proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route, change the parameter to be passed,

```
res.render('sku_item_detail', {"data": data.result[0]});
```

In view,

```
th submit Date : #{data.sku}
```

Hope this helps..!

Comment: thanks a lot! it worked! sorry I cannot up vote due to low rep. but i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your route change the parameter to pass the value as json.

```
res.render('sku_item_detail', {"datavalue": data});
```

And, in jade template set the variable as

```
th submit Date : #{datavalue.sku}
```

Comment: unfortunately, no luck :( it wouldnt create any difference in terms of output thanks for trying though

Comment: did you restart your node.js app? what output or error message are you getting?

Comment: it did not produced any error message but if i inspect element it says <p>submit Date :</p>.